# Access bearer token from in C# Library Project

Tags: c#, bearer-token

I have bearer token I am using in WEB API.

```
  var tokenUrl = Configuration["Api:BearerTokenUrl"];
```

Now, I want to access this in C# Library Project which is developed in .NetFramework 4.5

How can I access the bearer token in C# Library Project from App Config. I tried below and it is not working

```
var tokenUrl = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BearerTokenUrl"];
```

Comment: I understand that, I am storing the url of the token not the bearer token itself

Comment: Chatra - @Marie was right, though, and that comment is still valid for the question as stated. You should edit your question to be more accurate. Someone else is likely to come along and make the same comment now that it was deleted.

Comment: @Chatra - Are you pulling the value from a .json file in Web API project?

Comment: You referred to it as a "C# Library Project". Does that mean that you have control over the implementation of that library and can adapt it as you see fit?

Comment: @madreflection Yes I have control and can adapt it

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are pulling a value from a JSON file in the Web API, so it probably looks something like this.

```
{
    "Api": {
        "BearerTokenUrl" : "{Value}"
    }
}
```

And you are retrieving like so:

```
var tokenUrl = Configuration["Api:BearerTokenUrl"];
```

All you need to do is match the naming convention in your libraries App.Config

```
<add key="Api:BearerTokenUrl" value="{Value}"/>
var tokenUrl = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Api:BearerTokenUrl"];
```

Comment: I tried this but it is not working. I am getting the url but it is not authorizing

Comment: It sounds like you need to pass your token from one service to another in the request. are you passing the token on the request as an Authorization Header with the Bearer {tokenValue}?